# How To Verify A Coin Without Original Contract Source Code?

Tags: solidity, tokens, ico, cpp-ethereum, verify

We are new to crypto. A while ago we created a coin (3DOM coin) with 14,000,000,000 units and stored them in our wallet on myetherwallet.com. We would like to deploy the token now but we do not have the original source code for the contract we used. We have the address of the wallet where the tokens are held, the private key for the wallet as well the contract ID, but we are having trouble filling out the following screen to verify. We do not know the original compiler type, etc.  Can we verify the contract with any arbitrary compiler selection? Is it possible to redo the contract with the same parameters?

https://etherscan.io/verifyContract

[image]

Any help appreciated.

All the Best,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a solution for this.

Etherscan will recompile the contract that you provide with the parameters that you provide. If the result matched the deployed bytecode, it will mark the contract as verified.

The thing is that even changing the number of optimization runs or the compiler version can change the resulting bytecode. In other words, you need to have the exact code that was deployed and know the exact parameters that were used if you want etherscan to match the bytecode that was deployed.

Comment: By the definition, you cannot verify source code if you do not have source code.